# How to convert a jks file to a p12 file in OpenSSL?

Tags: java, openssl

I have roamed the internet but found only solutions using keytool. The common solution using keytool is this here:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore keystore.jks -srcstoretype JKS -deststoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore keystore.p12
```

But how is this possible with OpenSSL?

Comment: You can't. The Java keytool understands both JKS and PKCS#12, but OpenSSL only the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with OpenSSL without Java. The JKS format is serialized Java objects. You need to be able to parse the Java serialization format which is not usual outside Java.

Converting JKS (or any KeyStore) into PKCS12 is reasonably easy in Java. You just enumerate the items from the source key store and store them in target key store.

Comment: Thank you! I am trying this right now but I am struggling. I would be very thankful again for your help on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60956214/convert-jks-to-p12-in-java